# How to turn a java.lang.Object into another type of object?

Tags: java, object, objectoutputstream, typeconverter

I can make my program write a `.dat` file with an array of `Node` (an object that contains registry information:name,telephone numbers,...) using `ObjectOutputStream`, but I am having problems reading this same file, since the file contains an object that is different from the `Node[]` I used earlier.

My problems will be solved if I can make one of them:

- Converting the read `Object` into an object type `Node[]`, or
- Read a file as something like `readNode[]();`

I don't known the official name for this, so I am having problems finding an answer.

Comment: If the `Object`-typed expression *really* represents a `Node[]` then a *cast* will work: `(Node[])theObjectRead`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the file contains an object that is different from the `Node[]` I used earlier"?

Comment: i used objectoutputstream to write the file, but when I use readobject(), it returns me an object of the type java.lang.object, the file was written using writeobject(tree);(tree is an array of Node)

Comment: I will search more about this type casting, if I find an answer I will report it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object returned from the ObjectInputStream will have the same type it had when you wrote it to the file in the first place.

You will have to cast it at runtime, though, because the compiler cannot know what type that will be.

```
 Object obj = stream.readObject();
 Node[] nodes = (Node[]) obj;
```

If your format is flexible, so that you do not know what exactly to expect, you can use instanceof to check the various possibilities first.

```
 if (obj instanceof Node[]){
     // do something
 }
 else if (obj instanceof String) { 
     // do something
 }
 else {
    throw new IOException("unexpected object in data stream "+ obj);
 }
```